# Excel vba make excel believed saved until real change has happen

Tags: vba, excel

Scenario:

1. Workbook opened
2. screenupdate, calculation(Manual) events are set to false
3. Userform Show and user inputs some values.
4. User push ok
5. Populates values on sheet from userform
6. workbook saved
7. screenupdate, calculation(automatic) events are set to true

When user then tries to close the application without doing anything in the workbook it prompts the save dialog.

Not a big problem but irritating :) Any way to get around this?

Comment: Maybe switch the order of  6 and 7. Do you have any volatile functions?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the workbook's Saved value to true? Something like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
```

Comment: Hi, jepp. added it to the last line of code right after i have saved the workook. But still it ask me to save..

Comment: OyvPet, it needs to be put after the code for step 7. It won't save the workbook, just make the application think it has been.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this sort of thing in my own code, which in my case is almost always due to volatile functions. You could have the following in the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

This should work, though it could have undesired consequences if the user makes changes after the userform closes, changes that they don't want to keep.

Comment: Absolutely possible, but as you mentioned cahnges they dont want to keep is a issue. The workbook is also located on a server and some times run on a limited speed VPN connection. and im trying to only auto save when nessacarry when i already has som kind of progress form running. :) But yes, its a workaround...